# Equivalent function GetPackageFamilyName() function for driver Framework

Tags: windows-kernel

'''
LONG GetPackageFamilyName(
  HANDLE hProcess,
  UINT32 *packageFamilyNameLength,
  PWSTR  packageFamilyName
);
'''

this function requires appmodel.h header file but it gives error when it is included in a driver development project.

Actually i am trying to find the package/family name for a processes pid but i can't find am appropriate function for this.
I am trying to build a driver, if it is a normal .exe there is a above mentioned function that can help but it is a driver .sys and i am struggling now.
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use any such Win32 or Store App or UWP API from kernel-mode.  I doubt there is any notion, in the kernel, of app-model packages.  Why would you need to know the app-model package family name, in a driver?  You could develop an associated user-mode service, and develop a means for the driver to communicate with the service (DeviceIoControl()), and have the driver pass the PID to the service, and then the service open the handle to the process, and invoke GetPackageFamilyName(), and communicate the name back to the driver.

Comment: @asynchronos  can you just show me a code snippet which performs your explanation or using DeviceIoControl() in c++

Comment: er, no.  I wrote such code about 20 years ago and no longer have it available to me.  DeviceIoControl() is used to call *from* user-mode down to kernel-mode (and return a response in a buffer), so you have to get clever to use it to issue requests *to* user-mode from kernel-mode.  For example, the call to DeviceIoControl() is issued before the driver needs services from user-mode, then the driver completes it when it needs help from user-mode, and the response buffer contains the request.  A subsequent DeviceIoControl() can be used to communicate the results back to your driver.